# Use result of bash comparison in another comparison

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to use the result of a comparison in a subsequent comparison. I'm trying to do something like:

```
# $1 - expected result
# $2 - actual result
function print_result() {
    if [[ [[ $1 -eq 0 ]] -eq [[ $2 -eq 0 ]] ]]; then  # invalid
        echo "Pass"
    else
        echo "Fail"
    fi
}
```

I can get the desired behaviour with the more verbose form:

```
function print_result() {
    if [[ (($1 -eq 0) && ($2 -eq 0)) || (($1 -ne 0) && ($2 -ne 0)) ]]; then 
        echo "Pass"
    else
        echo "Fail"
    fi
}
```

but it seems like there should be a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something which produces the result of the comparison operator as text rather than as a status return. That would be [*arithmetic expansion*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion): `$((expression))`.

Note also that bash includes a numeric [conditional compound statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) -- `(( expr ))` -- which is often easier to use for numerical comparisons than the non-numerical `[[ ... ]]` conditional compound statement.

Putting that together, what you are looking for is:

```
if (( $(($1==0)) == $(($2==0)) )); then
```

Or just:

```
if (( ($1==0) == ($2==0) )); then
```

If you only want to know if $1 and $2 are both zero or both non-zero, then you can use the fact that boolean not (`!`) always evaluates to either 0 or 1. Consequently, the following even simpler expression is equivalent (but see warning below):

```
if ((!$1 == !$2)); then
```

Important: If you use that in a script, it will work fine, but at the command prompt you need to put a space after the `!` to avoid it being interpreted as a [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) character (unless you've turned history expansion off: if you don't actually use history expansion, turning it off is not a bad idea.)

Answer (score 1):

A possibly slightly more readable (but not particularly simpler) way would be to store the result of each comparison in a variable and then compare the variables:

```
function print_result() {
    [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]; arg_one_is_zero=$?
    [[ $2 -eq 0 ]]; arg_two_is_zero=$?
    if [[ $arg_one_is_zero -eq $arg_two_is_zero ]]; then
        echo "Pass"
    else
        echo "Fail"
    fi
}
```

There might be a better way to store the logical result (exit code) of a comparison in a variable but I couldn't find one after a quick look.